# Failed to generate token

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda, anaconda3

I wanted to generate a token to be able to work with a notebook from another laptop, but I got the following error:

```
A/.pm2/logs/jupyter-error.log last 15 lines:

5|jupyter| mod = importlib.import_module(modulename)

5|jupyter| File "/A/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/_init_.py", line 127, in import_module

5|jupyter| return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

5|jupyter| File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

5|jupyter| File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

5|jupyter| File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked

5|jupyter| ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator'

5|jupyter| [I 09:13:19.980 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /A/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab

5|jupyter| [I 09:13:19.980 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /A/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab

5|jupyter| [I 09:13:19.981 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /A/jupyter

5|jupyter| [I 09:13:19.981 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:

5|jupyter| [I 09:13:19.981 NotebookApp] http://10.20.23/

5|jupyter  | [I 09:13:19.981 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

5|jupyter  | Unable to connect to VS Code server.

5|jupyter  | Error in request
```

**Note:** I have crossed out some information for security.

I tried updating the library with pip or conda, but it won't let me update or install the libraries. The following error appears:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9ce8a9f518>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',)': /simple/jupyter-nbextensions-configurator/
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter-nbextensions_configurator (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for jupyter-nbextensions_configurator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to update Python, however there were several work environments with different versions of Python, it was only to configure the work environment and it recognized the libraries.